# Distribution for third cumulant?

Tags: probability-distributions, cumulants

It is well known that a probability distribution whose cumulants are all zero except for the first two is gaussian:

$$ f(x,\mu,\sigma^2) \propto\exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}) $$

So I'm wondering what the equivalent formula is for a distribution with three nonzero cumulants, or better yet a formula for n cumulants if that exists somewhere.

Comment: According to Wikipedia page on cumulants, no such distributions exist - the cumulant generating function cannot be a finite polynomial of greater than degree two.

Comment: Relevant CrossValidated question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41358/why-can-a-polynomial-of-degree-2-not-be-a-cumulant-generating-function

Comment: As a nit, the function you quote is the Gaussian density; the Gaussian distribution is an error function.